# Multiple widget for same field?

Tags: entities

I have defined some extra fields for User information in `configuration > account settings > manage fields`.

One of these fields is of type `List (text)` and the widget I have chosen for it is `Select List`.

I want to display this field using `Select List` widget in **Profile Edit Form** but as `Check boxes/radio buttons` in **User Register Form**.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using form_alter hook you can alter the type of field. I am assuming you are using Drupal 7. The below code will alter the **field_working_as** List (text) profile field in user_register_form in to checkboxes.

And the same field will show as selectbox in profile edit page. I hope this will help you.

```
function mycustommodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    unset($form['field_working_as']['und']['#options']['_none']);
    $form['field_working_as']['und']['#type']='checkboxes';
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked! but what does the unset function does?

Comment: It just removed unnecessary '-None-' option from checkboxes list :)

Comment: You should also be using LANGUAGE_NONE instead of 'und'. Or better yet, use the current language